# Can FoxPro use a JAR file?

Tags: java, .net, dll, jar, foxpro

I have some code in a jar file written in Java.  I want to use use my JAR in Fox Pro.

I've been told that it is not possible to call a function inside a JAR file with Fox Pro.

Is it possible for FoxPro to call a function in a jar file?  If so how?

Comment: are you claiming that a JAR file can be imported from FoxPro? @EricLeschinski

Comment: Unless the FoxPro guys spin up a JVM within their environment this will never work

Comment: What about IKVM ?@Petesh

Comment: which is pretty much the same as spinning up a JVM within their environment. If it's the original FoxPro then it's not actually .NET, so they'll have to do some remoting to get into IKVM and then into your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible for **FoxPro** to call a function written in a java **JAR**.  Not unless you want to write a Java Interpreter in a dead language.

You can probably, however, make an **ActiveX** or **COM*** wrapper for your java code, and then use the resulting object.  Java appears to have a "JavaBeans ActiveX Bridge" interface.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/activex-142114.html

Depending on how much Java and FoxPro code you have, you may have better luck going the other way, and having Java either read FoxPro data using OLE DB or invoking a FoxPro-based COM object.  The OLE DB should be easy enough to find, and there's a "JACOB" project on sourceforge to let Java read COM.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/

If neither of those are practical for you, you could always do what the GNU folks would, and wrap your Java code into a simple command-line application.  Not sure how you'd get the data back, precisely, but if nothing else you could always modify your java code to write a text file into `%TEMP%`.

Comment: Thank yo for this intresting answer, this question is old so i already used JACOB. i wished you could have answered me before :)